# How to fight spam on my signup form in php website?

Tags: php, spam, spam-prevention

I have a website which provides optional sign up.
Recently, I have been getting too many sign-ups which seem to be spam. Though I implemented email verification, the accounts keep getting added, and moreover, are even activated as soon as they are created.

I also added a hidden input field in the form and check if it is filled or not, but that too doesn't seem to work.

Any help?

Comment: You could implement a captcha.

Comment: I am trying to avoid captcha, for the very reason that it hampers user experience. Any other good method available?

Comment: You could also add some kind of creative captcha. Like is on that picture a cat or a dog or something like at what river is near the town cologne at the Rhein.

Comment: If a honeypot (hidden field) isn't working, then perhaps try dynamically creating a field using javascript, then require the user to do something to the field (check a checkbox, answer a simple math question, etc).

Comment: Can it be that the field id not working because I have used type=hidden instead of using CSS to hide it? I did this because display:none in CSS was unable to hide the field..

Answer (score 1):

Yeah , Make use of **`CAPTCHA.`**

> A CAPTCHA (an acronym for "Completely Automated Public Turing test to
>   tell Computers and Humans Apart") is a type of challenge-response test
>   used in computing to determine whether or not the user is human.

Here's a [`library`](https://code.google.com/p/cool-php-captcha/) available. Check out.

Include this library on your Signup Form .. and do like this

```
session_start();
$captcha = new SimpleCaptcha();
// Change configuration...
//$captcha->wordsFile = null;           // Disable dictionary words
//$captcha->wordsFile = 'words/es.txt'; // Enable spanish words
//$captcha->session_var = 'secretword'; // Change session variable
$captcha->CreateImage();
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this would be using Captcha.
A very common and good Captcha is ReCaptcha.
[The link to this can be found here.](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Recaptcha is very easy to install and google provides all of the Libraries necessary. Installing it is basically copying and pasting,but you do have to sign up with google.

Comment: Well the comments say that he want to avoid it.